# Greater Then with fake numbers from time formula EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that works out the diffrence between 2 times:

```
=IFERROR(IFNA(TEXT(H2-Q2,"dd - hh:mm"),"noData"),B2)
```

[image]
What I need to do now in the next cell (S2) is:

1. Anything that is =< 00 - 00:40 Mark as Late
2. Anything that is  > 00 - 00:40 Mark as Early
3. Anything that is ="noData" Mark as noData

I have tried a few things but as it is not a number it is not working.

Comment: Forget about your dd - hh:mm text and work with the original calculated H2-Q2 value.

Comment: Thanks for the help on that one, used  =IFNA(IF(H2-Q2<=0.028,"Late","On Time"),"noData") to get it to work.